# Word + "-associated" (Simplified and clarified)

Tags: compounds

Would you agree that the expression "a ragtime-associated song" implies that *those who expressed their views on this song* associate it with ragtime ?

While "a ragtime-related song" implies that this song is *inherently and objectively* related to ragtime ?

Answer (score 1):

Ragtime is a style of music but, as with all music styles, there is considerable variation and disagreement about what exactly fits that genre or does not fit it.

I think the phrase "ragtime-associated" doesn't really convey the meaning of what you are trying to express.  I suggest that alternatives to that might be:

> - "a ragtime-like song"
> - "a ragtime-style song"
> - "a ragtime-ish song"

Comment: Thanks, I realize I have not been precise enough. What I want to convey is that some _music-educated_ people (musicologists, scholars, writers, critics, etc), who have expressed their views on this song, associate it with ragtime, although not all of them do.